# PHP - Facebook API ( Invalid OAuth access token signature )

Tags: php, facebook, api, authentication, sdk

i'm trying use facebook API to upload photo in my fan page. I downloaded that code ready to do it ( https://www.box.com/s/a116a94bff8cb2a46634 ) . Its working good, but, when i edit and put my settings to upload the photo, i have this error...

**Notice: Undefined variable: fanpage_token in /home/sistemasfox/www/enc/face/uploadtopage.php on line 101
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token signature. thrown in /home/sistemasfox/www/enc/face/library/facebook.php on line 543**

Page ID: 239132959534036 / Album ID: 241768162603849

I copied the token from here : face book.com/tools/access_token/

I'm doing tests here: http://sistemasfox.com.br/enc/face/uploadtopage.php

Is necessary to make some configuration specified in the facebook application?

Thank you.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free debugging tool. Ask the original code developer about why they made such mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and paste line 63  of `uploadtopage.php`, and after pasting, change the variable from `$access_token` to `$fanpage_token`

See if that works?

i.e.:

`$access_token = 'AAAAARH40cT0BANFh5V7Cn8dlXciZCbonSmGQZCeX3kUKIx2OMmvrqKUsHIBBj6bYi2vV25lMj6ZA5UDOaJpAxJXBEMOjZAcZD';`

`$fanpage_token = 'AAAAARH40cT0BANFh5V7Cn8dlXciZCbonSmGQZCeX3kUKIx2OMmvrqKUsHIBBj6bYi2vV25lMj6ZA5UDOaJpAxJXBEMOjZAcZD';`

Comment: Oh, thank you, it work but i can just upload in my personal page, if i put the fan page album's id he returns this error
( "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#120) Invalid album id thrown in /home/sistemasfox/www/enc/face/library/facebook.php on line 543" )

The album's ID its facebook.com/243554175758581

Comment: Without reading every line of the code it's going to be difficult for me to debug - it would be much faster for you to email the author I think!